# Possible to compress a directory with Rar.exe to todays date.rar?

Tags: windows, batch-file, rar, winrar

How do I compress a directory with Rar.exe to (todays date).rar with use of a dos batch file?
Or do I need to use another file compression program?

Ty

Edit: Ive tried using %date:~10,4%%date:~7,2%%date:~4,2% as filename but it only works sometimes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this command:
rar.exe a -ag+YYYYMMDD arc {FolderName}

Answer (score 0):

Here is the command:

```
c:\path\to\rar\program\rar a C:\path\to\archive\backup.rar *.*
```

Comment: maybe my "" comfused u a bit, i meant that the filename to compress to should be Todays Date, so i need to load it from something. tried o %date:~10,4%%date:~7,2%%date:~4,2% but it only works every 2nd time